# Javascript Algorithm to Filter Contact Details

Tags: javascript

I am building a Chat App, and am looking for a way to remove any contact details a user may have in their messages.

i.e. I need to **filter** a string object in **Javascript** removing all strings that match the following and replace them with a line of ******:

- Phone Numbers
- Email Addresses
- Place Addresses
- etc.

**Questions**

Is this possible?
Are there any existing formulas I can make use of?
Is there anything in Javascript?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to iterate over all the `user` properties values with `Object.keys(user)` and make a replace if something found:

```js
var user = {
      phoneNumbers: '+34123456789',
      emailAddresses: 'user@example.com',
      elaceAddresses: 'some place address 1234' 
    },
    chat = document.getElementById('chat'),
    message = document.getElementById('message');

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var messageStr = message.value,
      p = document.createElement('p');

  if (messageStr === '') {
    return;
  }

  Object.keys(user).forEach(function(key) {
    messageStr = messageStr.replace(user[key], ' ****** ');
  });

  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messageStr));
  chat.appendChild(p);
  message.value = '';
});
```

```html
<h2>Chat app</h3>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="message" value="My phone is: +34123456789">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="chat"><div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. My problem is I don't know what users contact details will be. I was thinking if there is some sort of pattern matching algorithm out there? For example, Apaches OpenNLP is a Java library that recognizes language, and you can extracts all nouns from a sentence for example.

Comment: You have to make that `user` variable and fill it with their values.. I just added a demo and some code on how to replace the message string  `messageStr` for the *****.. Hope it helps;)